# How many subrings does $M_2(\mathbb{Z}/2 \mathbb{Z})$ have?

Tags: abstract-algebra

I know that there are 32 possible subsets of $M_2(\mathbb{Z}/2 \mathbb{Z})$, for one to be a subring, it must be closed under multiplication and subtraction. The zero matrix and the diagonal matricies will work, so there's at least three.

---

I think there are 9.

Comment: I looked at subrings where all of the elements are 0, where 1 is $a$, where 1 is $a$ and another is $b$, and one where it was the ring itself.

Answer (score 0):

The list of subrings of $M_2(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})$ can be found along the lines in the following paper: http://www.renyi.hu/~maroti/scorza.pdf . I did not count all subrings, but there are many more than $9$. Already the subrings with $2$ elements are given by $R=\{0,A \}$, where $A$ is a matrix with $A^2=A$ or $A^2=0$, i.e., 
$$
A=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \cr 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \cr 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 \cr 1 & 0\end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 \cr 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \cr 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \cr 1 & 0\end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \cr 0 & 1\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \cr 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \cr 1 & 1\end{pmatrix}.
$$ 
and then there a several subrings with $4$ elements (see the above paper), and also with $8$ elements, such as
$$
R=\{ \begin{pmatrix} a & c \cr 0 & b\end{pmatrix} \mid a,b,c \in M_2(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}) \}, 
$$
and
$$
R=\{ \begin{pmatrix} a & 0 \cr b & c\end{pmatrix} \mid a,b,c \in M_2(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}) \}, 
$$
and finally $R=M_2(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})$.

Comment: Why on earth should one count non-unital subrings of a unital ring? i.e. applying some random forgetful functor and only then considering subobjects? Stay in the category (universal lesson - after 100 years still not accepted). $M_2(\mathbb{Z}/2)$ is a unital ring, so consider unital subrings.

Comment: Have a look at the above paper, why non-unital subrings of $M_2(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})$ are of interest. Of course, I agree if we talk about the category of unital rings. But why on earth should one count then unital subrings of $M_2(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})$, for that matter ?